# How would one use an optional linq paramter on a joined table that doesn't include a foreign key?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Let's say you have these two tables:

```
CAR
ID  Name
1   Toyota Camry
2   Honda Accord

CAR_PART
ID  CarID   Name
1   1       Brake Pad
2   1       Mirror
3   2       Brake Pad
```

For certain reasons, it is impossible to establish a foreign key relationship between `CAR_PART.CarID` and `CAR.ID`

There is a search page where users can search for cars and car parts, and every search field is optional (the search should default to all results unless filtered by these optional filters).  The requirement is to establish a base query on the `CAR` table (see below) and then optionally join in `CAR_PART` if needed (if the user wants to filter).

Here is what I have so far:

```
//the base query
var query = dbContext.CAR;

//optional: CAR name
if(model.CarName != "")
{
    query = query.where(c => c.Name == model.CarName);
}

//optional: join in CAR_PART table and filter on CAR_PART.Name **NOT WORKING**
if(model.CarPartName != "")
{
   query = query.Include(p => p.CAR_PART).where(p => p.Name == model.CarPartName);
}
```

This `CAR_PART` join is where things break.  Because there is no foreign key relationship between `CAR_PART.CarID` and `CAR.ID`, Linq does not allow the Include to work.

How would you allow for this optional search parameter?

---

**Environment: 
Entity Framework version 4.0, 
Linq-to-SQL**

Answer (score 1):

You make it a compound condition like below and use equality operator instead of assignment operator

```
query = query.Include(p => p.CAR_PART)
             .Where(p => p.Name == model.CarPartName || p.Name == model.CarName);
```

Comment: Woops, yeah should have been == instead of =.  This has been fixed in the example.  Concerning your example, I don't think this .Include would work since there is no foreign key relationship between the two tables.  This is the issue I am facing: not sure how to handle an "odd" situation like this.